# CKEditor - добавление собственного шаблона (экранируются атрибуты тэгов)

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.addTemplates("default", {
templates: [{
    title: "CONTAINER",
    html:
    '<h3 class="info-left-title">Заголовок H3</h3>'
    }]
});
```

Такой шаблон в самом редакторе возвращает

```
<h3>Заголовок H3</h3>
```

без атрибута `class`. В чем может быть проблема? Это же происходит и с `h2`,`p`.
Пробовал:
`'<h3 class="info-left-title">'+'Заголовок H3'+'</h3>'`, `'<h3 class="info-left-title">Заголовок H3'+'</h3>'`, в конфиге писал `config.allowedContent = 'h3[*]';`, - все равно `class` экранируется.
С `div` - все ок.